# Track a Rails project on private repo on GitHub with Redmine and Integrity deployed on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, heroku, redmine, integrity

## Scenario

- Project **A** is a Rails application:

  - Code hosted on GitHub on a ***private repo***.
  - **Deployed on Heroku** (which has a readonly file system).
- Project **R** that is an instance of [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), used to manage my project **A**:

  - Code hosted on GitHub on another ***private repo*** (same GitHub account).
  - **Deployed on Heroku** (which has a readonly file system).
- Project **CI** that is an instance of Integrity, used to continuous integrate (by running tests) my project **A**:

  - Code hosted on GitHub on a third ***private repo*** (same GitHub account).
  - **Deployed on Heroku** (which has a readonly file system).

### What I want

I want to be able to:

1. Use the *Repository* feature on Redmine on project **R** (in essence, to be able to see the repository from project R).
2. Run the tests on CI.

### My problem

To clone and keep up to date the code of project A on both project R and project CI.

### What I tried

For the 1. point, I've tried to follow the instructions found on http://www.redmine.org/wiki/1/RedmineRepositories, with the only difference that I've created the local bare copy of A into the root of R (because of Heroku's constraints on file system), which caused the creation of /*A.git* dir.

After that, I've re-deployed on Heroku the project R, and in the Redmine's project A settings I've configured as SCM "Git" and A.git as Path to .git directory (I've also tried ./A.git).

However, when I point to the tab Repository of A project on Redmine, I got a 500 with message:

"The entry or revision was not found in the repository."

Where am I wrong?
Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is currently impossible to integrate Git or Mercurial repos with a Redmine instance running on Heroku due to the read-only filesystem constraint. I asked Eric Davis and he thinks so too. SVN and CVS don't require Redmine to have a local copy of the repo, and so I think they work, whereas Git and Hg don't.